# Spark xxhash64 not consistent across execution environments

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hash, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use the Spark 3.0 DataFrame API built-in function [`xxhash64`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.xxhash64.html) to generate a `long` primary key column given a subset of columns like this:

```
df_with_id = df.withColumn(
        "CONTRACT_IDENTIFIER",
        xxhash64(
            "SOURCE_SYSTEM",
            "SOURCE_SYSTEM_CONTRACT_IDENTIFIER",
            "CONTRACT_INCEPTION_DATE",
        ),
    )
```

I have also created a unit test that compares the `DataFrame`s with the generated IDs for equality. However, it looks like the generated hash code is not consistent across execution environments (JVMs?) because the test succeeds when run locally but fails when executed in an integration test Spark cluster.

So my question is whether this is something that is expected and whether there are other ways to achieve the same thing, i.e. create a row ID by hashing a subset of columns?

Comment: I don't think its expected. xxhash suppose to generate hashes _"identical across all platforms (little / big endian)."_ (https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash)

Comment: I tried `md5` instead of `xxhash64` and it seems to be stable, i.e. no difference in generated hash. I'm wondering if this is a bug in `xxhash64` implementation? Anyway, `md5` is the recommended way to create surrogate keys anyway (to avoid collisions), so I'll go with that one (just had to change the data type of the ID column from `long` to `string`).

Comment: Are you computing with Spark in both cases? b/c I noted today that Spark computes xxhash64 starting with seed=42, which is not where most impls would start (seed=0)